# Wordpress: Error establishing a database connection

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Out of no where my working Wordpress site came up with a "This site is currently unable to handle this request." The only change I had made was adding the ajax_load_more plugin, and it had been working for about an hour before quitting on me.

Because of that error page, I tried restarting the server.

When the server powered back on I got a page saying "Error establishing a database connection."

I then tried to figure out if mysql was down and there were no issues there, however I could no longer login to mysql with the username and password I have had setup for Wordpress to login to the database. This password has gone unchanged site I created the site about a month ago, along with the wp_config file. However, I was able to login using the root username and password.

I then tried creating a test page:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "****";
$password = "********";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

This test page did not work with either the wordpress login that I created, or the root login. 

Other info:
Host is Digital Ocean
LEMP Build (https://www.wpintense.com/2017/06/12/installing-and-configuring-fastest-possible-wordpress-stack-digital-ocean/)
Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Sounds like you need a system admin..  These questions are off topic for SO as it seems like you're having a problem with your database server, not with coding.

Comment: Yes, but I'm a one man team so that isn't going to happen any time soon. And I am having some sort of problem with something on the server. Not coding

Comment: Well, you probably shouldn't be using digital ocean or any unmanaged VM without a system admin available.

Comment: Well it's too late for that. I need the access to be able to make changes to the server without being blocked from everything like most hosts do, so my bosses chose digital ocean and here we are. I have 3 other wordpress sites and multiple other sites on Digital ocean, all of which are running fine. I just need help with this one thing. Also the questions aren't off topic it's a series of events that lead me to where I am. I am including all the details so others can help me best

Comment: It'll work until it crashes or you're hacked... then  you end up in this situation.  Not sure what you expect for anyone here to tell you.

Comment: I expected an answer. Even that one would have been helpful. Thanks

Comment: It's unlikely you've provided any info that would help diagnose the problem.  My recommendation is to hire a system admin that can log in and review your database server to find the cause and potential solutions.

Comment: The question is off topic --it's not a programming question. You are being given sound, solid advice -- get a system admin. There is no way we can know your setup, your software, your server configuration, etc. We cannot help other than to tell you to search the internet for guides on troubleshooting MySQL connections.

Answer (score 0):

This error basically means that the credentials given in the wp-config file do not match up to your database details. I must stress that these details are completely separate from your server details.
It's not completely clear what you're up to so I'm going to start from the beginning to get your site up and running again. First, I want you to rename your current wp-config.php file to something like wp-config.php.old (the name doesn't matter).
Then create a new wp-config.php file with the following within:

```
<?php
/**
* The base configuration for WordPress
*
* The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
* installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
* copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
*
* This file contains the following configurations:
*
* * MySQL settings
* * Secret keys
* * Database table prefix
* * ABSPATH
*
* @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
*
* @package WordPress
*/

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name_here');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'username_here');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
* Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
*
* Change these to different unique phrases!
* You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret- 
key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
* You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This 
will force all users to have to log in again.
*
* @since 2.6.0
*/
define('AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here');

/**#@-*/

/**
* WordPress Database Table prefix.
*
* You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
* a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
*/
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
* For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
*
* Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
* It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
* in their development environments.
*
* For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
* visit the Codex.
*
* @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
*/
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Next, you will need to find out the correct details.
When you log into your server, you should be able to access the database via phpMyAdmin or something similar. 
Most servers will allow you in without having to login to the database. Once you're in, you will need to create a new user for your database. This is what will go into your username and password fields in the wp-config file.
Make sure this user has ALL privileges or it won't work.
The name of your database will go in the database field and the hostname is usually 'localhost' but you may need to contact your hosting if this doesn't work.
I have heard that the hostname might be your website's URL but I'm not sure whether that is accurate or not.

I hope this provides you with enough information to get your website back on track. Let me know if you experience any more issues and I'll try my best to help you out!

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling your plugins by doing a folder rename and then see if your site comes up again. You can do the entire plugins folder or just the one you think is causing the problem. Do it from the backend file administrator that you should have access to ( all webhosts give this out by default for you to be able to manage the site's files and folders )

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access your phpmyadmin?

If not, you have reached your server memory resources limit.

You can change your droplet size or optimize the site. Most of the cases it will only fix with optimizing the site.